# VS2015 publishing errors

Tags: c#, publish

So I'm trying to publish my .net application using Visual Studio 2015, and every time that i upload the files to the website, and then i enter the URL to my browser, it just automatically downloads the .aspx file instead of showing it like it should? What should I do?

Comment: Which hosting do you use?

Comment: Can you provide more detail in how are you "publishing" the application?

Comment: I am using TrentaHost

Comment: I am "publishing" the application by simply zipping up the entire project and unzipping it to my public html. I have tried "publishing" using the FTP, and the result is the same when I zip and unzip on the website file manager in the control panel.

Comment: Are you sure that the server has ASP.NET (or Mono) installed and configured correctly?  If it is a Linux server, it probably doesn't unless you have explicitly looked for one that does or asked.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this question. I purchased a Windows VPS after this, installed IIS, then just contacted my web host to map the domain to the IP of the new VPS. And it worked.